# how to applylinearimpulse at a right angle

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I have calculated an angle:

```
float spriteAngle = ccpToAngle(ccpSub(rSpriteOne, rMid));
```

How can I add 90 degrees to spriteAngle and applying a linear impulse at the resulting angle on a body. Please Help, i've been at it for a while.

Comment: Hey did you find your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try out `ccpRotateByAngle` inline cocos2d function